# How can I write my own decorator in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-decorators

My **`models.py`** file  is as follow:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Shopkeeper(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    # ...


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
# ...
```

And I have some views which only Customers can access after login, but Shopkeepers cannot. And vice versa.
How can I write decorator for such task?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing magical about a decorator, it is a function that takes as input the function (or class) to decorate, and makes some changes to it. If we look at the [**`login_required`** decorator [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L38), we see:

> ```
> def login_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
>     """
>     Decorator for views that checks that the user is logged in, redirecting
>     to the log-in page if necessary.
>     """
>     actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
>         lambda u: u.is_authenticated,
>         login_url=login_url,
>         redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
>     )
>     if function:
>         return actual_decorator(function)
>     return actual_decorator
> ```

We can thus actually simply make a special case of the `user_passes_test` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def shopkeeper_required(function=None):
    def is_shopkeeper(u):
        return Shopkeeper.objects.filter(user=u).exists()
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(is_shopkeeper)
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    else:
        return actual_decorator

def customer_required(function=None):
    def is_customer(u):
        return Customer.objects.filter(user=u).exists()
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(is_customer)
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    else:
        return actual_decorator
```

You can then for example implement it as:

```
@login_required
@shopkeeper_required
def some_shopkeeper_view(request):
    # ...
    pass

@login_required
@customer_required
def some_customer_view(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

Note that this `@shopkeeper_required` does *not* really enforces that the user is logged in, although in many cases that will be the case.

**EDIT**:

We can merge this with a `@login_required` (by adding a parameter that acts as a switch to turn this behavior on or off, by default on), like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def shopkeeper_required(function=None, login_required=True, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    def is_shopkeeper(u):
        if login_required and not u.is_authenticated:
            return False
        return Shopkeeper.objects.filter(user=u).exists()
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        is_shopkeeper,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    else:
        return actual_decorator

def customer_required(function=None, login_required=True, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url=None):
    def is_customer(u):
        if login_required and not u.is_authenticated:
            return False
        return Customer.objects.filter(user=u).exists()
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        is_customer,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    else:
        return actual_decorator
```

Comment: How can I merge `@login_required` with this custom decorator ?

Comment: `actual_decorator = user_passes_test(u.is_authenticated and is_shopkeeper)` will it work?

Comment: No!. SInce at that point there is no `u`, `u` exists because of the `lambda` expression, so that should be `user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_authenticated and is_shopkeeper(u))`.

Comment: `'User' object has no attribute 'login_required'`  when a customer is already logged in and a request to a view which a shopkeeper can access is passed then  your edited code give error given above.

Comment: @AbidMehmood: hi, I made a typo. It is now fixed :).

Comment: What does this mean `redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME` ?

Comment: How do I make my own Redirect? since if it return False, I want to go to the home page, not the **accounts/login**

Comment: @AnonymousUser: use `@shopkeeper_required(login_url='<path-for-home>')`.

Comment: It went to **accounts/login**, even if I used `@shopkeeper_required(login_url='')`. I then tried adding `@shopkeeper_required(login_url='home')`, and that worked. My path name to home is `name='home'`, and the path is `''`.