# How to return error message in decorator in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I wrote my own decorator, which checks if the currently logged in user is a teacher. If not, the decorator redirects the user to the login page, but for the user it is a bit confusing, so I want to pass a message why the user was redirected to the login page, but I have no idea how to do it.

```py
# here is my decorator:
def teacher_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='login'):
    '''
    Decorator for views that checks that the logged in user is a teacher,
    redirects to the log-in page if necessary.
    '''
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_teacher,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the build-in [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/) from Django with a custom decorator.

For this, Django provides full support for cookie- and session-based messaging, for both anonymous and authenticated users.

In your case, an example would be the following:

decorators.py

```
# Import Django messages
from django.contrib import messages

# Custom Decorator
def teacher_required(function):
    def _function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_teacher:
            messages.info(request, 'Custom message to user')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app:url_name'))
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return _function
```

views.py

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from foo.decorators import teacher_required

@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
```

In this case you have to call the decorator with `@method_decorator()`, and pass the `login_required` first, to ensure that the user is logged in before checking if he is a teacher.

If you want to implement a more elegant system, I have found an example on [github](https://gist.github.com/edwinlunando/3af8f1eae9bbd67cb647).

Answer (score 1):

Decorator is a function that takes as input the function (or class) to decorate, and makes some changes to it. I would go for a two method option, in which if the first method is true then they're genuine teacher, else they're not and in such case give them a valid output.

```
def teacher_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='login'):
    '''
    Decorator for views that checks that the logged in user is a teacher,
    redirects to the log-in page if necessary.
    '''
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_teacher,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
```

We can simply make a use case for the decorator `user_passes_test`

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def teacher_required(function=None):
    def is_teacher(u):
        return Shopkeeper.objects.filter(user=u).exists()
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(is_teacher)
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    else:
        return actual_decorator
```

You can then for example implement it as:

```
@login_required
@teacher_required
def teacher_view(request):
    # ...
    pass

@login_required
def not_teacher_view(request):
    # ...
    pass
```

I hope you get the idea, for clarity see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127599/6505847)

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with build in messages framework. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/

To use if you have to follow the steps:

Make sure you have django messages added in installed apps in your settings.py.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'django.contrib.messages',

    ...
]
```

Configure the messages storage by adding the following line into your settings.py:

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```

Add message in your decorator before returning the actual_decorator:

```
messages.warning(request, 'Access restricted, for teachers only')
```

and than if you use bootstrap you could display alters in your template in following way:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
    {{ message }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

the documentation for bootstrap alerts can be found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/