# how to build a bookmark system in django as in instagram

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I wanna build this bookmarking system like in Instagram, I'm having problems writing the logic in views.py and displaying it. So what I want is to bookmark "Act" based on "act-id's" to Wishlist model if a user is authenticated and it would be better if we use Ajax for the post-call(when clicked on the bookmark icon) or open to new options really. Here's my current code... Please help me! if you need any extra bit of code just lemme know.

models.py

```
class Act(models.Model):
    label1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    label2 = models.ImageField(blank=False, null=True)
    label3 = models.IntegerField(('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    label4 = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class Wishlist(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    act_id = models.ForeignKey(Act, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def wishlist(request):
    act_id = request.POST.get('act_id')
    if not act_id:
        raise ValueError("Required act_id to set wishlist")
    user_id = request.user.pk
    try:
        act_id = Act.objects.get(pk=act_id)
        wishlist_obj = {
                        'user_id': user_id,
                        'act_id': act_id
        }
        Wishlist(**wishlist_obj).save()
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse('Some error occured, unable to add to wishlist')
    return HttpResponse('Added to wishlist')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login_req, name='login'),
    path("logout/", views.logout_req, name="logout"),
    path('home/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('wishlist/', views.wishlist, name='wishlist'),
]
```

for more context here's a conceptual pic of home.html

[image]

[image: error img]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my view on how you can do this.

> Wishlist the **model if a user is authenticated** and it would be

I always prefer to use `decorators` to check if the user is authenticated. You can see here on how to achieve this - [Writing your own decorator for login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127563/how-can-i-write-my-own-decorator-in-django). And then you can then simply apply `@login_required` to check if the user is authenticated or not.

You can also simply check in the `views.py` using the `is_authenticated` attribute to check if the user is logged in or not.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
  # do something if the user is authenticated
```

> it would be better if we **use Ajax for the post-call**(when clicked on the bookmark icon)

I would also recommend an `Ajax` request to update this as this suited to an asynchronous task. You can see the example [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) on how you can write the `ajax` function. But in short, once the user clicks the `bookmark` button the ajax request will be made to the function in `views.py` with the relevant `post` data , you can then simply add your desired operations in the function.

**Edit:**

*The problem is rather broad and though I do have a few solutions, writing most by words will simply get convoluted for you to take anything out of but I shall give it a try!*

So given that you have the model which saves and displays the card which has been wish-listed; therefore in undoing that operation, you would simply have to reverse-engineer the logic using Ajax. So, firstly when a user clicks to undo a card that has been wish-listed, you make an ajax call, e.g. [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) and then in your `views.py` you simply verify if the clicked element is indeed is wish-listed by checking that the object exists in your database.

If it exists, you then simply return a success `JSonResponse({})` from the function in `views.py` and then in your

```
success: function (response) { }
```

in your `Js` you simply add the relevant `HTML` code to unlist the card from the wishlist.
A good example is shown [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/work-with-ajax-django) that demonstrates how you can use `JSON` and `ajax` to update the unlisted card.

Comment: I have problems writing the views.py logic(creating the wishlist), in general words, this system I'm trying to build works like an Add to Cart button on an ecommerce store except I want to use Ajax for the post req, I'm not able to create the logic, if u can please help me with it, thnx tho!

Comment: You need to elaborate on the logic that you are referring to.  Have you read the link above for creating your ajax post request? You would simply need to work it around the way you need

Comment: I would if my logic was right, so about the logic, I've these cards in my home.html if someone clicks on the bookmark icon on a specific card, that specific card gets saved on Wishlist view(wishlist.html) and if someone un-clicks on that specific icon, it gets unsaved without reloading the page(this is where Ajax comes in), so I'm not able to write that logic, get me? would really appreciate your help if you can do this thnx

Comment: @Falcon I have edited the answer and added the best possible way around this. Do read and let me know if you have any doubts; but also in the latter case consider fully understanding the links that I have mentioned as they're vital in going about solving your problem. Meanwhile, if my answer has been helpful do consider upvoting/accepting the answer.

Comment: nah I get you but what I'm saying is I don't hve the Wishlist model working, think of it like I'm running the wishlist-view-function with pass statement I don't hve any code with it so I need to build it right? that's wht I need the help with, Ajax come later and its not really the issue here. thnx for ur time, really appreciate it! and if u wanna go about solving this then probably use something like repl.it and share the link, cheers mate!

Comment: Ahh. I cant think of a way other than this `I don't hve the Wishlist model working,`. Solve this and my method will work on this. If this answer helped in your problem, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer.

Comment: I don't have the problem with Ajax really